# htmlWebpackPlugin add only one entry point to the generated html

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

Below are the webpack config entries :

```
entry:{
    background: './app/main/background.js',
    options: './app/main/options.js'
}
```

One HTML page which is suplied to htmlwebpackplugin as below

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template :'./app/templates/options.html',
    // chunks : ['jquery','angular','app'],
    filename: "./options.html",
    cache : true
}),
```

This results in injecting both `background.js`, `options.js` in the `options.html` page as below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/background.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/options.js"></script></body>
```

Is there a way to restrict it to only one JS file or specify the file names to be injected in html page?

Comment: Honestly it seems like this should just be an option in the plugin. Not sure how this has not been implemented after all these years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you can use [html-webpack-exclude-assets-plugin](https://github.com/jamesjieye/html-webpack-exclude-assets-plugin)

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    excludeAssets: [/style.*.js/] // exclude style.js or style.[chunkhash].js 
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackExcludeAssetsPlugin()
]
```

Answer (score 23):

The `chunks` option is probably what you want to use (see the [filtering chunks section](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#filtering-chunks) of the documentation). I don't know why it's commented in your snippet but you could write this:

```js
entry: {
    background: './app/main/background.js',
    options: './app/main/options.js'
}
```

If you want to only inject the `options` entrypoint in the generated HTML, specify the chunks:

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template :'./app/templates/options.html',
    chunks : ['options'],
    filename: "./options.html",
    cache : true
}),
```